# Call external API from Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM online

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dataverse

I want to call an address verification API (Green ID) on CRM Accounts and Contacts.
There are two API POST methods to call in two triggering points,
1 - Basic_Verification() needs to be called when a flag field (ready to verify) is changed to true
2 - Specific_Addr_Verification() needs to be called when a user manually clicks on a Ribbon button on the form (PowerApps form Command)

This is a SOAP API, and when calling the API POST methods, I have to build the SOAP message body using the Account/Contact record details.

I am not sure what is the ideal way to develop this functionality. The options I am considering are as below,

1. Create a custom API and MS Flow (Power Automate) to call the API. Then trigger the flow using action, power fx row update or by javascript. Please suggest the best approach for each of the two scenarios above.
2. Create an HTTP request in power automate and trigger it on row update
3. Directly call the API using javascript function (webresource) on button click and form field update events
4. Custom plugin triggered by the event, c# code to send web requests

Or else please suggest any other suitable implementation methods for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong solution. All are suitable viable options, based on your requirements/reusability needs - one or other approach is recommended.

I’ll explain what we did recently, we had some enterprise level Mulesoft APIs and we developed custom connectors around that API. So now all CRM dev teams can use that connector in their Flows based on their needs. Even if needed Flow can be invoked from JS web resource..

Basically it’s standard best practice at each level, therefore it can be rationalized later on. Some opinions will come this is as an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I built a similar functionality multiple times and the following architecture always worked fine for me:

1. Create Action/Custom API with inputs that accept an address and outputs that return the result of validation.
2. Develop the plugin that performs the validation based on provided inputs and tie it to the Action/Custom API you created in the previous step.
3. Create a JavaScript that handles changes of the address field/on-demand call from the button to call new Action/Custom API and consume the result.

One cool thing in that kind of placing of webservice calls into Action is reusability - it would be possible to use the same mechanism wherever you need it - from JS Code, from other plugins/workflows and lastly from external apps/integrations, great example is Power Automate Flow.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you very much for the answer.
To clarify, where is the actual API request written in this approach? Is it inside the plugin code as a HTTP request? Does that mean the creation of the SOAP request is done as a string concatenation work by inserting the input parameters?
Is there a better way to create the SOAP request using MS Flow or Power Automate?

Comment: Calls of external API in this approach will reside in plugin behind the Action/Custom API.

Comment: Hi, May I know how are you generating the token in this case? I have similar requirement to search addresses from a third party api hosted in Mulesoft.. The thing that worries me is generating the token, every single time user enters a letter after x chars, the plugin will geneate the token and call the API.. in reality the token generation call could be unnecessary as the previous token is still valid..

Comment: In a perfect world how would I do it is I would expose additional input/output parameters for your token. In the first call - a token is generated and returned to the calling side where it's preserved and used for the other sequential calls. Once it expires - regenerate the token on the server side and return it through the output parameter.